# How do I control the direction of flow for Fancybox Galleries?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have Fancybox 2.0 working here: http://discovermonroeville.com/photo-gallery

My only question - which I was unable to find an answer to in the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) is how do I get the gallery images to flow from left to right instead of top to bottom?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.photo-gallery').fancybox(); 
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frmz, i investigate you code and found that in you fancybox js file below option is missing:

```
direction : { next : 'left', prev : 'right' }
```

Download the fancybox js file once again.

Comment: Hi Kudan, should it be like this:  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.photo-gallery').fancybox(); 
   direction : 
    { 
     next : 'left', 
     prev : 'right' 
    }
   });
 </script>