# Fancybox mouse wheel direction change as horizontal

Tags: jquery, fancybox, mousewheel

As you know, mouse wheel direction is running as up/down. I want to change this as left to right or reverse. I have tried as followed but it did not run.

```
$(function() {
    $(".fancybox-outer").mousewheel(function(e, o) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (o * 30);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Show a demo or link to the site please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I control the direction of flow for Fancybox Galleries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356729/how-do-i-control-the-direction-of-flow-for-fancybox-galleries)